# Probability, Statistics - Whats the answer?

Tags: probability

Assume that a programmer makes on average two errors in every hundred lines of code
written and that errors occurring in different lines of code are independent. Suppose the
programmer writes a software application consisting of 75 lines of code.

a. What is the probability that the application contains no errors?

b. What is the probability that the application contains exactly one error? Show
your working

I don't even know how to start!

Pls can someone help me!

Comment: The problem gets more complicated if you count multiple errors occurring in the same line.  Have you heard of Poisson distributions?  If so, André Nicolas's answer is probably the right interpretation of the problem for you to use.  If not, it might be okay to assume that each line has at most one error.  (I think the resulting difference in the answers will be very small anyway.)

Comment: The thing is we were given a brief introduction to probability of binomial dist. and this question relates to the hidden answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I am assuming in my answer that this is a question about binomial probability. I am assuming that there can be no more than one error per line.

I'm not too sure how to give a hint without giving it all away, so here are solutions (in spoilers - mouse over at your own risk!):

a.

> P(Error in One Line) = 0.02. (Multiply by 100: he makes two errors every 100 lines.) So P(No Error in One Line) = 0.98. So $0.98^{75}$ is the probability of no error in all 75 lines, because the events are independent, so you just multiply them.

b.

> We can do this with the [binomial formula](http://www.mathwords.com/b/binomial_probability_formula.htm), which we use to calculate P(n successes in k trials). We're looking for $P(k=1)$. We have $n=75$ trials and a probability of 'success' $p =0.02$. The binomial formula is: $${n \choose k}p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} = {75 \choose 1}\cdot 0.02^1 \cdot (1-0.02)^{74}$$ You can do the computation.

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable to suppose that you are expected to use a **Poisson model**. The mean number per $100$ lines of code is $2$, so the mean per $75$ lines of code is $(0.2)(75)=1.5$.

So we model the number $X$ of errors in $75$ lines by a Poisson with $\lambda=1.5$.

The probability that $X=0$ should then be about $e^{-1.5}$. The probability that $X=1$ should be about $e^{-1.5}\frac{(1.5)^1}{1!}$.

Comment: This is just an approximation, right?  For the given problem it's not hard to find the exact answer.

Comment: The underlying structure can be taken to be binomial, though not so clearly if there can be more than one error per line.

Comment: Oh, good point---I hadn't considered the possibility of more than one error per line.

Comment: We will presumably soon know what is intended. If OP has never heard of the Poisson, then the binomial model is intended. If Poisson has been introduced, then probably Poisson is intended, it is an early type of exercise for the Poisson.

Comment: No I am not taught Poisson distribution yet. But we are taught probability of binomial distribution.

Comment: Then you are expected to use $\binom{75}{0}(0.2)^0(0.98)^{75}$ for probability of $0$ errors, and $\binom{75}{1}(0.02)^1(0.98)^{74}$ for the probability of $1$ error.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  First find the probability that a given line of code (say the first line, because it doesn't matter) contains an error.

Comment: @user2923027 That's right.

Comment: Ok. Im thinking. Let me come back to you in 5-10 mins. I really appreciate your help. Pls wait.

Comment: Darn! It was a bit hard for me and I couldnt resist looking at the answer above this post. The answer above makes so much sense. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2923027 You're welcome.